# Why does Onelogin Implicit Flow return Error 410 Gone?

Tags: api, authentication, session, token, onelogin

I am trying to setup implicit flow authentication for my web app.  The requests is as follows:

```
https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/auth?client_id=<clientId>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:<PortNr>/MyApp/signin-custom&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid+email+profile&nonce=12345&state=<someStateHere>
```

Am I missing something?

I have an OpenId Connect (OIDC) App setup in OneLogin, tried all Token EndPoint Types, but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I got it wrong, here is how it is supposed to be:

```
https://<subdomain>.onelogin.com/oidc/auth[...]
```

All fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Dr Malchev's answer is the best answer. For completeness you could also use

`https://api.eu.onelogin.com/oidc/auth[...]`

However, using `<subdomain>` instead of `api.eu` is preferred.